# I am using qrcode_reader package in my flutter project but it's giving me an error

Tags: flutter

I am using - 
`dependencies:
  qrcode_reader: ^0.4.4`
that's the latest version available. And it works perfectly fine when I flutter run on my phone. But when I Gradle Sync the project on Android Studio it's giving me an error. I couldn't find any solution for that problem. 
    Here is the Error -

```
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 1,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.matheusvillela.flutter.plugins.qrcodereader" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update *build.gradle* file of your *app* to have `minSdkVersion 16` like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Did you update gradle file on path _[project_name]/android/app/build.gradle? Try to remove android:minSdkVersion from _AndroidManifest.xml_ if it is specified.